# How to validate if a remote Docker container has changed?

Tags: docker

I'm pulling with: `docker pull <someimage>:<sometag>`.

How can I validate that the remote tag has changed? So I can:

```
if [ CHECK_IF_REMOTE_TAG_IMAGE_HAS_CHANGED ]; then
    docker rm <someimage>:<sometag>
    docker pull <someimage>:<sometag>
fi
```

This comes in handy when using containers where the tag = `:latest`.

Comment: I'm surprised `docker search` doesn't return the last updated date for the container when that information is available on the website UI. If you could get that, combined with `docker history image:latest` should be enough

Comment: I am not sure if there's a reliable way unless the docker registry you use provide an API to retrieve latest version/tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [container-diff](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/container-diff) to compare container images when both images are tagged with <strike>version</strike> `latest`.

Comment: `latest` is not a version, It's yet another tag to label a build which didn't set a specific build tag. How does this work if the next version of `latest` build of the container has built with a specific tag like 1.0?

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately `container-diff` seems to not work at all. https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/container-diff/issues/305

Comment: @BobvanLuijt literally just ran `container-diff` before dropping into this question. Try it with your images.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker inspect -f {{.Id}} mongo:latest
```

Gives you the Id of the image which changes with each build [guessing docker build is what is used to change/modify image] - I am unsure of the behaviour when docker save is used. Sample Dockerfile to change the image mongo:latest and new tag as mongo:test1

```
FROM mongo:latest
COPY ./test.txt /tmp

$> docker build -t mongo:test1 .
```

Shell script to compare mongo:latest and mongo:test1

```
ID1=$(docker inspect -f {{.Id}} mongo:latest)
ID2=$(docker inspect -f {{.Id}} mongo:test1)

if [ "$ID1" == "$ID2" ]
then
    echo "Same Image"
else
    echo "Image changed"
fi
```

Output

Image changed