# Universal way to check if container image changed without pulling that works for all container registries

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, containers, docker-registry, fluxcd

I'm writing a tool to sync container image from any container registry. In order to sync images, I need a way to check if local `image:tag` is different from remote `image:tag`, possibly through comparing image sha ID (as image sha digest is registry-based). Due to the nature of my tool, pulling image first then compare using `docker inspect` will not be suitable.

I was able to find some post like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55226174/how-to-validate-if-a-remote-docker-container-has-changed) or [this](https://ops.tips/blog/inspecting-docker-image-without-pull/). They either tell me to use docker v2 API to fetch remote metadata (which contains image ID) and then compare with local image ID or use `container-diff` (which seems like it was made for a more complicated problem, comparing packages in package management systems inside images). The docker v2 API method is not universal because each registry (docker.io, grc.io, ecr) requires different headers, authentications, etc. Therefore, `container-diff` seems to be the most suitable choice for me, but I have yet to figure out a way to simply output `true/false` if local and remote image are different. Also, it seems like this tool does pull images before diffing them.

Is there anyway to do this universally for all registries? I see that there are tools that already implemented this feature like fluxcd for kubernetes which can sync remote image to local pod image but is yet to know their technical details.

Answer (score 0):

On a high level your approach is correct to compare the SHA values, however you need to dive deeper into the [container spec](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec), as there is more to it. (layer and blobs)

There are already tools out there that can copy images from one registry to another. The tools by default don't copy the data if the image already exist in the target. [Skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo) is a good starting point.

If you plan to copy images from different registries, you need to cope with each registry individually.  I would also recommend you to take a look at [Harbor](https://goharbor.io/.). The Harbor Container Registry has the capability to copy images from and to various registries built in. You can use Harbor as your solution or starting point for your endeavor.